# Webpack: how to go up one or more levels in respect to __dirname?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, directory

The below config works, but I have the reason to move webpack configuration from project root. As result, `__dirname` value will change and I need to go to upper lever in respect to `__dirname`. How to do it?

```
const output_path = isDevelopment ? (__dirname + '/development/devBuild') : (__dirname + '/public');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        'open/js/testOpenEntryPoint': './development/source/open/es6/testOpenEntryPoint',
        'admin/js/testAdminEntryPoint': './development/source/admin/es6/testAdminEntryPoint'
    }

    output: {
        path: output_path,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const projectRootDirectory = __dirname + '/../../..';
const output_path = options.isDevelopment ? (projectRootDirectory + '/development/devBuild') : (projectRootDirectory + '/public');
```

will do.

Comment: I think a slighly safer way would be to use `path.resolve` like this: `path.resolve(__dirname, '..','..','..');`

Comment: Do I need to require `path = require('path')`? Currently, the `path` variable is not available.

Comment: Yes. You can require it at the top of your script. Or if you only plan to use `path` once, you could do `require('path').resolve(__dirname,'..','..','..');`